# if $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \cos^{2n}(\theta) =5$ then what is $\cos(2\theta)?$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> if $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \cos^{2n}(\theta) =5$$ then what is $\cos(2\theta)?$

The confusion that I am having is with the answer key that I have which says that the sum of the geometric sum is the following:

$$\frac{1}{1-\cos^2(\theta)}$$

But that didn't make any sense to me because if n=1 which means the first term, then that means that the first term should be the following

$$\frac{\cos^2(\theta)}{1-\cos^2(\theta)}$$

According to the answer key, the first term is 1 but that would mean that $n$ would have to be $0$

Is the answer key truly wrong or is there something that I don't understand?

Comment: The "answers at the back of the book" are often wrong.

Comment: Either your answer key is wrong or you've made some error in copying the problem.  $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \cos^{2n}(\theta)=1/(1-\cos^{2}(\theta)$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown an edit has been made, please see if it changes anything * I copied the question wrong

Comment: @BrianBorchers an edit has been made, please see if it changes anything I copied the question wrong

Comment: @BrianBorchers so if n=0 on the sigma, does that mean that 0 is the first term? *sorry I'm very new to sequences and series

Comment: $(\cos\theta)^0=1$

Comment: @JohnRawls `if n=1 which means the first term` You don't get to choose $n\,$, that's just an index into the sum defined to go from $n=0$ to $\infty\,$. What you *are* probably expected to know and recognize here is that the sum of a geometric series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n = 1 / (1-x)\,$ when $|x| \lt 1\,$.

Answer (score 2):

The book is correct. You have simply forgotten that the sum starts at $n=0$ and not at $n=1$, so the first term should be $\cos^{0}\theta = 1$, which clearly holds for all $\theta \neq \pi n$